# Bitshifting value returned by implicitly declared function producing wrong result

Tags: c, function-declaration

There are **two functions** returning the **same value**. One of the function is **not declared**. Bit shifting both the values by the same constant produces different results. Cannot get a handle on what's is happening underneath. Can someone provide some light. Here is the code

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

//unsigned int fun1();
unsigned int fun2()
{
        return 3064476672;
}

int main() {    
        unsigned int b = fun1() >> 8;
        printf("Bit shift result of function 1: %u, \n", b);

        b = fun2() >> 8;
        printf("Bit shift result of function 2: %u, \n", b);    
}
```

**func.c**

```
unsigned int fun1()
{
        return 3064476672;
}
```

**Result with `fun1` undeclared**

Bit shift result of function 1: 4290160692,

Bit shift result of function 2: 11970612,

**Result with `fun1` declared**

Bit shift result of function 1: 11970612,

Bit shift result of function 2: 11970612,

Comment: Lots of UB with `unsigned int fun1()` assumed to be `int fun1()`.  Save time, enable all warnings.

Comment: Your C implementation uses 32-bit `int`. When `fun1` is not declared, it assumes the return type is `int`. When the actual `fun1` returns the `unsigned` value 3064476672, which is out of the `int` range, your C implementation is interpreting it as the corresponding `int` value 3064476672−2^32 = −1230490624. When it shifts this right 8 bits, it gets −1230490624/256 = −4806604. When you pass this `int` value to `printf` and ask it to print it with `%u`, it interprets it as the corresponding `unsigned` value, −4806604+2^32 = 4290160692…

Comment: … While this is effectively what happened in this instance, the behavior is not defined by the C standard and should not be relied on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your C implementation uses 32-bit `int`. When `fun1` is not declared, it assumes the return type is `int`. (This stems from C language history, when `int` was a default type. It is not called for by the current C standard.)

When the actual `fun1` returns the `unsigned` value 3064476672, which is out of the `int` range, your C implementation is interpreting it as the corresponding `int` value 3064476672 − 2<sup>32</sup> = −1230490624. (Because of this mismatch in types, the behavior is not defined by the C standard.)

When your C implementation shifts this right 8 bits, it gets −1230490624 / 256 = −4806604. (Right shifts of negative values are implementation-defined. The arithmetic shift used by your compiler, which effectively replicates the sign bit of a two’s complement representation when shifting right, is common.)

When you pass this `int` value to `printf` and ask it to print it with `%u`, `printf` interprets the `int` value −4806604 as the corresponding unsigned value, −4806604 + 2<sup>32</sup> = 4290160692. (Due to the mismatch in types, with `%u` requiring `unsigned` while you are passing an `int`, the behavior is not defined by the C standard.)

While this is effectively what happened in this instance, the behavior is not defined by the C standard and should not be relied on.

Answer (score 2):

The program has undefined behaviour:

- In C99 and later, due to calling an undeclared function (this is a constraint violation in fact);
- In C89, due to calling an undeclared function whose definition is not compatible with `int f();` .

Since the behaviour is undefined, anything can happen -- which includes unexpected output.

Comment: It is factually untrue that, when the C standard does not define the behavior, anything can happen.

Comment: @EricPostpischil are you looking to start a philosophical discussion? I suppose it will not happen that pi changes to equal 3

Comment: It is not philosophical. As my comment clearly states, it is a matter of fact. It is untrue that anything can happen. When the C standard does not define the behavior, a C implementation remains governed by its own specification, by the properties of the system it operates in, by the specifications of its hardware, by laws regulating consumer products where applicable, and by physics and logic. Furthermore, these things have significant practical consequences. One is that beginners can be scared that doing things wrong may break something. They should be reassured they can experiment freely…

Comment: … Another is that debugging would be impossible or difficult if the statement that anything can happen were true. In fact, the actual consequences of doing things that are not defined by the C standard often have recognizable symptoms or patterns that give clues to the problem, and these can be used to diagnose, find, and fix the problem. It does a disservice to students to tell them “anything can happen” when we ought to be helping them learn more than just “Here is the edge of the C standard; if you go further, you will fall off a cliff and cannot be helped.”